# Why isn't json_decode() function working?

Tags: php, json

This is the code:

```
    $json = "{ a: 'hello', b: 'world' }";
    var_dump($json);
    var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

The first outputs:

```
{ a: 'hello', b: 'world' }
```

The second outputs nothing. I want the second to output something like:

```
array(
    'a' => 'hello',
    'b' => 'world'
)
```

How to do this? Is my JSON format wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running a `json_encode` on your example output, to see what it generates?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Keys in JSON must be "-quoted :

```
{"a": "hello", "b": "world"}
```

also, you can use php's `json_last_error()` when you need to know what went wrong :).

Comment: This is one of the first things I tried but with single quotes. Guess it needs to be double quoted. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Properly formatted JSON requires keys and string values to be enclosed in double-quotes. Change it to this:

```
$json = '{ "a": "hello", "b": "world" }';
var_dump($json);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is no proper [JSON](http://json.org/). You need to have quotes around property names and string values.

Try

```
$json = '{ "a": "hello", "b": "world" }';
```

Answer (score 3):

Because that is not valid JSON.  The following is the appropriate form:

```
{"a":"hello","b":"world"}
```